# Unable to get value in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have following code.

```
<ul class="multi-list tabs">
<li class="width-50 selected"><a class="first" value="123456">Mark Complete</a></li>
<li class="width-50"><a class="last even" value="123456">Delete</a></li>
<input type="hidden" name="wo[sub_complete_ids][]" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="wo[sub_delete_ids][]" value="">
</ul>
```

I am trying to get value of li.selected a.first but its displaying undefined.

My trial code is

```
console.log( $("ul.multi-list li.selected a.first").val() );
```

What wrong in it as it not displaying the value. Expected value is 123456.

Furthermore, this ul can be multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$().attr()` instead of `$().val()` because the later one is for input field. Preferably use jQuery's `$.data(selector,key,value)` method to store and retrieve data in html element. The following snippet will get the value from the first link.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      alert($('ul.multi-list li.selected a.first').attr('value'));
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="multi-list tabs">
  <li class="width-50 selected"><a class="first" value="123456">Mark Complete</a></li>
  <li class="width-50"><a class="last even" value="123456">Delete</a></li>
  <input type="hidden" name="wo[sub_complete_ids][]" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="wo[sub_delete_ids][]" value="">
</ul>
```